# use powershell to print a list of files inside a folder and its subfolders

Tags: windows, powershell, file

i need to print all the files included in a folder and its subfolders.
i tried with this command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\mypath\' -File -Recurse | Out-File -FilePath 'c:\mypath\files.txt'
```

If i run the first part alone, i get the result in powershell with no errors, but if i run the full line, i get the following error

```
Get-ChildItem : The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\XXX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ReadError: (C:\Users\XXXX:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOExcep
tion
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

how to fix? is there also a way to print only the files with their path in the same line? I'd need a file in a similar format

**filename size lastEdited path**

thank you so much

Comment: It works for me - I think the problem is with your machine.  Have you tried a reboot? ..or maybe save to another disk?

Comment: it might be a filename too long... how to fix eventually? is there a way to format the output the way i need it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get it into the format requested you just need to use `select-object` to choose the items of interest:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\mypath\'  -File -Recurse | 
select-object name,length,lastwritetime, fullname | 
out-file 'c:\mypath\files.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you, when i run it without the out-file part, i get a list of files including only the file name... why? how to get the other data too? sadly i get the same error when printing...

Comment: i tried changing the second line to select name, length, lastwritetime, fullname and it's almost ok, the problem is that it cuts the name and fullname... any way to avoid the trim?

Comment: It will only cut it on the screen - the export to text file should print out everything.  You need to work out why it won't let you save the file.  Have you tried to `out-file` to an alternative location - perhaps an alternative drive letter?